# How to make sqlite output to table

Tags: sqlite

I want to use sqlite query and I want to do the outter join several times. So after each join query I want to get my output as a new table. Can sqlite implement that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, that doesn't sound like proper use of SQL.  Each query, regardless of number of joins, will output one result set.  If you want multiple separate results (tables), then you need separate queries.